# Centralized Authorization Service?

Tags: security, authorization, soa, xacml, josso

Are there any open source centralized **authorization** services available?  There are lots of solutions for centralizing the authentication information (eg: [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) and [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home)), but what about the authorization information?

There are some really good authorization frameworks (eg: [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference/html/springsecurity.html) (formerly Acegi) and [Seam Security](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/latest-2.1/reference/en-US/html/security.html)), but it seems that I have to composite these into individual tiers or services.  In other words, I can't run them standalone very easily.  With a SOA, it seems like it would be very valuable to centralize not just the authentication but the authorization information as well (ie: roles, permissions, rules, etc.).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something that supports XACML? If so, the closest to open source you can get is the OpenSSO project which has portions of what you seek.

Answer (score 2):

The openly available [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) implementations provide [Client Service Authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)#Client_Service_Authorization) as well as [Client Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)#Client_Authentication).

Read about [Using Kerberos 5 on Red Hat Linux](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-7.2-Manual/ref-guide/ch-kerberos.html).

Answer (score 1):

Hum, maybe you can use a SSO solution and create a service which returns all the authorization information (roles, permissions, rules, etc) and make each application use this service to get each authenticated user authorization information.